GuardDuty analyzes CloudTrail event from unwanted regions
We are using AWS Amplify. I believe under the hood it uses S3, DynamoDB, and API Gateway.
Our app is a single country only (Let's say it is UK). However, after analysing costs for GuardDuty, I have noticed that all regions produced some CloudTrail logs. How can I make sure that I don't have any traffic to CloudTrail from other regions except the EU (London)?

